# How to compare date fields of different fields?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id   ref_id     dates
1       1      2017-01-01 00:00:00
2       1      2017-01-31 00:00:00
3       2      2017-01-01 00:00:00
4       2      2017-01-31 00:00:00
5       3      2016-01-01 00:00:00
6       3      2016-01-31 00:00:00
```

Query will be like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE dates  GROUP By ref_id
```

I would like to compare `ref_id` wise Start Date in 1st row & End Date in 2nd row should be between Current Date.

So output will be only those ref_id which are in between current date.

Output

```
ref_id
1
2
```

or GROUP_CONCAT of that 1,2

Would like to using single query without UNION.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ref_id
FROM table
GROUP BY ref_id
HAVING NOW() BETWEEN MIN(dates) AND MAX(dates)
```

The query uses [**NOW**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) in order to get the current date/time value. If this value lies within the interval defined by the minimum and maximum date value of a `ref_id` group, then this `ref_id` is returned by the query.